# How do I right-click when connected to my Windows 7 PC from my Android Tablet?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, android, right-click

I have installed on my Acer Iconia 10 Android Tablet the Microsoft Remote Dektop application. I've successfully connected to my PC from my Tablet, and now I have a really, really basic question -

How do I right-click?

Comment: Use Ericom instead, it has a very nice mouse emulation.

Comment: i can't right now; I'm three states away from where my home PC is, so for now I'm stuck with this one. Also, please do not recommend me other remote desktop programs; I would rather have a solution that does not involve changing from one application to another. I tried that one, and it nearly cost me money I didn't need to be spending. Thank you.

Comment: I ment using Ericom on your Android, to connect to the standard RDP on your WIndows PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Microsoft RD Client app then you simply tap and hold with one finger then tap with another.